# "The installer could not find a compatible JDK installation, specify it manually. The minimum required version is 1.6.0"

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I am trying to download NetBeans IDE 7.2.
While Installing, the installer displays the following message, "No Compatible JDK was found"
and then when I click Next, it asks me to select the directory that has the compatible JDK.
by displaying the follwing message:

```
"The installer could not find a compatible JDK installation, specify it manually. The minimum required version is 1.6.0"
```

I am sure that the directory that I specified contains JDK 1.8.0. However, the message remains there and I am not able to proceed.

Can someone help? I am using windows 32 bits.

Comment: are you sure that it holds JDK 8? I'm pretty sure that it's only early access currently. Latest GA release is JDK 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html

Use the Windows x86 version.
Filename: jdk-7u6-windows-i586.exe

You need to complete the installation, the SDK will be installed in:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06`

When you start the NetBeans 7.2 install afterwards, it will automatically find the JDK location.

Comment: should It be in Program Files?

Comment: I have tested it for you.
I downloaded "jdk-7u6-windows-i586.exe" and installed it.
The JDK now is in:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\"

Comment: When the JDK is installed into "C:\Program Files" correctly, NetBeans automatically finds it when you start the installer.

Comment: I did exactly what you said but the same message is still there, and I can't proceed

Comment: I just tested it on Windows XP 32 bits, Java SE Development Kit 7u6, NetBeans 7.2 Beta. NetBeans installes good and works.

Did you restart the NetBeasn install after the JDK install?
Do you maybe have old JDK's installed which you can uninstall via Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs?